# Need of vhost for zend application

Tags: apache, zend-framework

If running any zend application it is recommended to ceate the vhost.
Why is it so?

Although the public part form the url can be removed by copying the index.php and .htaccess file to root of project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... yes, technically can just copy index.php and .htaccess to the root of the project directory. However, by doing that you will expose all of your application files to the public.

For example, someone could try to access your config file like this: `http://yourhost/yourproject/application/configs/config.ini`
This will actually display the content of the config file (which might include sensitive data like your database configuration) unless you explicitly configure something in your .htaccess to prevent this.

When using a vhost with the DocumentRoot set to the public dir, that means that no file outside the public directory will be accessible from an URL. And since you should normally only have the index.php file in there, you ensure that your application is always accessed from that starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a simple explanation